# What is a pedestrian-friendly city?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, english

If a city satisfies a certain condition, it is a pedestrian-friendly city. Here's some examples.

| Pedestrian-friendly | Not pedestrian-friendly |
| --- | --- |
| Davenport | Fremont |
| Asunción | Dallas |
| Ikast | Istanbul |
| Tucson | Phoenix |
| Tampa | Irvine |
| Abidjan | Chicago |
| Indore | Dublin |

What is a pedestrian-friendly city?

Hint 1:

> The [word-property](/questions/tagged/word-property) tag applies. The [geography](/questions/tagged/geography) tag does not apply.

Hint 2:

> Iraq and Iran are pedestrian-friendly countries. Delaware is a pedestrian-friendly state. Tammy, Thomas, Augustín (note the accent!), and Inez are pedestrian-friendly people. Tacos are a pedestrian-friendly food.

Hint 3(a):

> Pedestrian-friendliness, in a sense, is all about meters...

Hint 3(b):

> ...but *initially*, it’s a matter of *feet*.

Comment: I am struggling to reconcile the presence of the tag [knowledge] with the first hint.

Comment: @Evargalo Yep, I could see that being confusing. (Not to mention the second hint!)

Comment: I think I know what the intent is here. Hint 3(a) confirms what I guessed after Hint 2 appeared, but I'm still at a loss to fit that to the given lists. ROT13(Vf gurer fbzr ertvbany inevngvba ng cynl urer? Sbe zr, Ghpfba, Gnzcn, Qnyynf naq Qhoyva nyy orybat va gur fnzr yvfg.)

Comment: @fljx Lbh'er irel pybfr. Gubfr orybat gb gur fnzr frg va bar frafr, ohg abg va gur bgure frafr.

Comment: @fljx Erjneq obahf uvag: Ghynar naq Veivar pbhyq or crqrfgevna-sevraqyl va fbzr abarkvfgrag ertvbany inevngvba, ohg Serzbag naq Cubravk arire pbhyq.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on hint 3(a) and 3(b), it's clear that this is about

> Poetic meters. The city name first letter ("initially" in hint 3(b)) must match the first letter of the meter of that word.
>  The list of meters (/ is stressed, x is unstressed):
>  * Iambic (x /)
>  * Trochaic (/ x)
>  * Spondaic (/ /)
>  * Anapestic (x x /)
>  * Dactylic (/ x x)

And the list of cities and their property:

> **D**avenport (**D**actylic)
>  Fremont (Iambic)
>  **A**sunción (**A**napestic)
>  Dallas (Trochaic)
>  **I**kast (**I**ambic)
>  Istanbul (Dactylic)
>  **T**ucson (**T**rochaic)
>  Phoenix (Trochaic)
>  **T**ampa (**T**rochaic)
>  Irvine (Trochaic)
>  **A**bidjan (**A**napestic)
>  Chicago (Dactylic)
>  **I**ndore (**I**ambic)
>  Dublin (Trochaic)

Comment: Well done. rot13(V nibvqrq fcbaqrrf, orpnhfr gurl'er fb fhowrpgvir bhg bs pbagrkg.)

Comment: Yea. I am not native English speaker, but I feel that can only appear in a phrase and not in a word.

Answer (score 1):

Could a pedestrian-friendly city be one…

> **that has its accent on the final syllable?**

The break in point for this was

> Augustín. I speak Spanish, so it all clicked with this and Hint 3A.

Here are some examples of it:

PEDESTRIAN FRIENDLY CITIES ARE:

> Moscow (mahs-KAU), London (lohn-DUHN), etc.

Comment: You’re on the right track, but your rule doesn’t fit cities such as Davenport or Tuscon. (It also doesn’t fit the two other cities you named; I think the English pronunciation is different for those.)

Comment: The English… ugh. Well, it has to be poetic, or something along those lines.

Comment: @parz your last comment is so close to the answer!